# Is there a way to force an android device to stay awake?

Tags: android

This app needs the device (and its display) to stay awake between onPreExecute() and onPostExecute().

Comment: Yep, these devices appear to be narcoleptic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a "full" `PowerManager.WakeLock` like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992508/using-a-wakelock-in-a-service-android-1-5).

eg:

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    wl.acquire();
```

Add permission to **manifest** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Make sure to release it when done.

Comment: Thanks--works great! Also need to add android.permission.WAKE_LOCK to manifest.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible - here's an example of an app which does that:

http://www.appsbeyond.com/apps/screen-suite

Answer (score 1):

"full" PowerManager.WakeLock is now deprecated and will lose support.

For future compatibility, use the following to force the app to stay awake:

```
// keep awake    
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

// allow suspend
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

No special permissions are required.

You will need to do this in the hosting activity. you could try nesting the AsyncTask, or using a callback interface implemented by the host Activity (think Fragment callbacks).

[Developer Reference](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html)