# How to force an android device to stay alive while the application is running

Tags: android, service, keep-alive

I need to force the android device to stay alive while the application is running. There any way to do this ? 
I read here : [Is there a way to force an android device to stay awake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660464/is-there-a-way-to-force-an-android-device-to-stay-awake) about this, I tried to do this but probably I don't know to use correctly a Service.

This is the code I use :

```
public class WakeLockService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    wl.acquire();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    wl.release();
}
```

and in the first Activity of my Application, I put this :

```
Intent s = new Intent(this, WakeLockService.class);
startService(s);
```

Is it correct what I'm doing? Anyone can help me to do this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please define "the application is running". Do you mean when a specific activity is in the foreground? Why did you create a service just to have a `WakeLock`?

Comment: This is what I found on SO. I don't know another way to make the android device to stay alive. Can you help me ?

Comment: **Please define "the application is running"**. Unless and until you can clearly explain what you mean by "the application is running", we cannot give you any reliable advice.

Comment: In my application I have, for example, a syncronization server->mobile and this syncronization can run more then 5 minutes. I want to force the device to not enter into stand-by, to see when the syncronization process is finished. I want to say that when the application is open on device, the device to stay alive and to not enter in stand-by mode.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the device to stay awake while it displays an activity of your app, you have to set the flag FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON when creating the activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD); // Unlock the device if locked
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON); // Turn screen on if off
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); // Keep screen on
    .....
}
```

Add the permission WAKE_LOCK in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

EDIT After seeing your last comment: yes, you need a service: note that the device will go to sleep anyway, but your service can continue to run if you make it clear to the user (you have to display a notification) and declare it STICKY:

```
public class yourservice extends Service
{
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        //The intent to launch when the user clicks the expanded notification
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Intent forPendingIntent = new Intent(this, si.test.app.activities.activity.class);
        forPendingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, forPendingIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "testapp", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "testApp", "testApp is running", pendIntent);

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        startForeground (R.string.app_name, notification);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> In my application I have, for example, a syncronization server->mobile and this syncronization can run more then 5 minutes. I want to force the device to not enter into stand-by, to see when the syncronization process is finished

The synchronization operation should be managed by some Android component, such as a service. That component can manage a `WakeLock`. Do not create some separate component purely for the `WakeLock`, as that other component has nothing whatsoever to do with your synchronization work.

For example, if your synchronization is being conducted via an `IntentService`, you could use [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) to keep the device awake while the work in `onHandleIntent()` is being conducted.