# Turn the screen OFF when plugged in to AC or USB and Turn it on when removed from the source

Tags: android

Before making this as duplicate:: I see a lot of threads supporting this, **but none of them works in waking up or turning the screen on when the screen is completely turned off (or in sleep mode)**.

My aim: when the USB is connected or the device is plugged in to AC power the screen has to turn off (that is happening), and when the power/ USB is unplugged the screen has to turn on back to the app. (not working).

**Note:** If the screen is dimmed out to the lowest instead of turning it off we can turn the brightness on back when required, but that is not what I want.

The links that is suppoting this questions are:
1. [wake-android-device-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621599/wake-android-device-up)
2. [is-there-a-way-to-force-an-android-device-to-stay-awake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660464/is-there-a-way-to-force-an-android-device-to-stay-awake)
3. [android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically)
4. [turning-on-screen-programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891337/turning-on-screen-programmatically)
5. [how-to-unlock-the-screen-when-broadcastreceiver-is-called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352548/how-to-unlock-the-screen-when-broadcastreceiver-is-called)

*Here is the code that I am using It successfully turns the screen OFF, but will not Turn it on.* You can also download the code project from : [Download Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwCRkER4bNnIRjdvdmNwRkMyWE0/edit?usp=sharing)

**Class Name: MainActivity**

```
package com.power.screenmode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.power.screenmode.BackgroundService.PowerUtil;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView txt_PowerConnected;
private boolean isChargerConnected = false;
private Context mContext;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams params ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    firstLoad();
    initViews();
    doTask();
    startService();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
   //   powerMethod();
    super.onResume();
}

private void firstLoad(){
    mContext = MainActivity.this;
}

private void initViews(){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt_PowerConnected = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_PowerConnected);
}

private void doTask(){
    isChargerConnected = PowerUtil.isConnected(mContext);
    params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    if(isChargerConnected){
        txt_PowerConnected.setText("Charger Connected");
        turnScreenOFF();
        System.out.println("Power Connected - doTask");
    }else{
        txt_PowerConnected.setText("Charger Not Connected");
        turnScreenON();
        System.out.println("Power Disconnected - doTask");
    }
}

private void startService(){

    try {
        Intent service = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
        startService(service);
        Log.i("SCREEN_MODE", "background service calling");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        // register the receiver to listen to battery change
        this.registerReceiver(this.receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
}

private void turnScreenOFF(){
    params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    /** Turn OFF: */
    params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
    params.screenBrightness = 0.0f; // 0.1f to turn the brightness to lowest
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
}

private void turnScreenON(){
    params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    /** Turn ON: */
    params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
    params.screenBrightness = 1.0f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);

    // I have tried the below method also but it didn't work\\\
//      powerMethod();
}

private void powerMethod(){
    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    final KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km.newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock");
    kl.disableKeyguard();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    if(wakeLock.isHeld()){
        wakeLock.release();
    }

}
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        if (plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC ||plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB ){ 
            System.out.println("Charger connected -- receiver");
            turnScreenOFF();
        } else{
            System.out.println("Charger Disconnected -- receiver");
            turnScreenON();
        }
    }
};
}
```

The Background service class:

```
             /**
     * 
     */
    package com.power.screenmode;

    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.os.BatteryManager;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.WindowManager;

    /**
     * @author Prasildas
     *
     */
    public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    public static final int INITDELAY_TASK = 0;
    public static final int INTERVAL_TASK1 = 1; 
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    public static ScheduledFuture<?> schedule_Background;
    private Handler tableUpdateHandler;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("SCREEN_MODE", "Started");
        tableUpdateHandler = new Handler();
        scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

        schedule_Background     = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task_CheckScreenMode, INITDELAY_TASK, INTERVAL_TASK1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
         Log.i("SCREEN_MODE", "Created background service --> Live Mode");
        }


    /**
     * To stop the background check 
     */
    public void stopBackgroundTask() {
        if (schedule_Background != null) {
            schedule_Background.cancel(true);
        }

    }

        /** The background task in the service  -- Shaking the cart with the badge numbers updating
         */
        private Runnable task_CheckScreenMode   = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                tableUpdateHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            PowerUtil.isConnected(getApplicationContext());
                            Log.i("SCREEN_MODE", "background running powerutil");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        public static class PowerUtil {
            public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
                Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
                int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
                return plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC || plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
            }
        }



        @Override 
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        @Override 
        public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }      

        @Override 
        public void onDestroy() {
            Log.i("SCREEN_MODE", "background service task 1 destroyed");
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
```

The Manifest File:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.power.screenmode"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.power.screenmode.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <service android:name="com.power.screenmode.BackgroundService" >
            </service>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```